# Change Spell Checking Language in Signal Messenger for Linux or Windows

Tags: language, spell-check, signal-app

I would like to use multiple languages simultaneously for spell checking (similar to the mail client Evolution or the Slack client or similar to Google Chrome or similar to the Android keyboard) or at least have an option to change the spell checking language.

I have installed Signal both on Linux (Fedora) and Windows 10.
For me the spell checking works only in the default language of my operating system right now.

Comment: Sound like the application is using the language of the operating system to handle the spell checking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to change the language in the app itself, and by extension to have a specific language per conversation, but there is [a feature request](https://community.signalusers.org/t/allow-setting-os-independent-language-during-installation-or-in-preferences/5978) you can vote for in the community forums.

In the meantime the application will use the system language, but it is possible to start it with a different language.

### On Windows

You must modify the Signal shortcut in the start menu:

1. Search for Signal in the start menu
2. Right click > Open file location
3. Right click on Signal > Properties [alt-enter]
4. Modify the *Target* by adding  `--lang=<language>` where `<language>` is your chosen language and region code, like `en_US`

Note: when updating Signal, you will need to quit and relaunch Signal from that shortcut, otherwise it will default again to the system language when  the update process relaunches it. Similarly you should disable autostart with Windows and always launch Signal from the shortcut.

### On Linux

You need to set both `LANG` (for spellchecking) and `LANGUAGE` (for interface language) variables.

Best is to create a custom `signal-desktop.desktop` shortcut in `~/.local/share/applications` (this might be OS- or Desktop Environment-specific) so that it does not get overridden after every update.

Start by copying `/usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`, then modify the `Exec` line to include your language, e.g.,

```
Exec=env LANG=fr_BE.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=fr_BE /opt/Signal/signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U
```

### MacOS

The Language & Region system preferences allow to set per-app preferences.